# Why 'or' operator is returning this output in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

This is my sample data:

```
name    age
-----------
amrutha 40
rajesh  30
harish  30
harish  25
rajesh  35
karthik 30
```

I wrote this query:

```
select * 
from interv_ex
where name not like 'harish' or age <> 30
```

I get this output from the query:

```
name    age
-------------
amrutha 40
rajesh  30
harish  25
rajesh  35
karthik 30
```

My questions is how only (harish 30) row got eliminated from the actual data, as per my understanding "or" operator, the rows which containing name "harish" or age "30" shouldn't been included in output, but name "harish" age "30" was returned.

Can anyone please explain how "or" operator works in above scenario?

Comment: There is no benefits of using `LIKE` if you're not using wildcards

Comment: `(NOT A OR NOT B) <-> NOT (A AND B)` - when A/B are NOT NULL. Boolean algebra: **[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)**

Comment: thanks for all ur replies , i forgot the basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Or operator it works like this

If one of the condition is True, your will the result.

```
True or True = True
False or True = True
True or False = True
False or False = False
```

name not like 'harish' or age<>30

```
amrutha 40  -- True or True
rajesh  30  -- True or False
harish  25  -- False or True
rajesh  35  -- True or True
karthik 30  -- True or False
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply,with some confussion i post this question that's  very simple  basic i forgot

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with SQL server and everything to do with the fundamentals of boolean algebra.

First, you need to consider what subexpressions your filter expression consists of. Some parentheses might help clarify what is going on.  Here is the exact same expression you have used, with parentheses added for clarity:

```
(name not like 'harish') or (age<>30)
```

So, this expression will select everyone whose name is not 'harish' and whose age is not 30.  Note how the use of the word 'and' in the english language is idiomatic and has nothing to do with boolean logic.  In boolean logic, A OR B means "true if either A or B is true".

Another way of thinking about it is that in order for a row to be selected, the following must hold true:

```
Either the name must not be 'harish' or the age must be different from 30.
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your expected output?

If your Expected output is something like this

```
name    age
-------------
amrutha 40
rajesh  35
```

Then you can try this solution

```
;WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 'amrutha' AS name, 40 AS age UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rajesh' ,30  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'harish' ,30  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'harish' ,25  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rajesh', 35  UNION ALL
    SELECT 'karthik' ,30 
)


select * from yourTable
where  age<>30 and name not like 'harish'
```